# ARM Template for Event HUB logger

Tags: azure-rm-template

I am automating some of my Azure deployments and have created automation for API Management instance as well as Event HUB namespace

As part of my APIs I have a log-to-eventhub policy

```
<log-to-eventhub logger-id="eventhublogger" partition-id="0">
```

I created a logger using the Rest API passing it a request similar to the following:-

```
{  
  "type": "AzureEventHub",  
  "description": "Sample description",  
  "credentials": {  
    "name": "apim",  
    "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://contoso- 
   ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=Sender;SharedAccessKey=..."  
  }  
}
```

Is it possible to create the logger in an ARM template instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is what I came up with

{
  // Event HUB Logger
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers",
  "name": "[concat(variables('ApimServiceName'),'/','eventhublogger')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
  "dependsOn": [

  ],
  "properties": {
    "loggerType": "azureEventHub",
    "description": "Log APIM requests and responses to Event HUB",
    "credentials": {
      "name": "[variables('namespaceName')]",
      "connectionString": "[parameters('eventHubNamespaceConnectionString')]"
    }
  }
}
```